# Is there a way to get URL for the image created using canvas from html or pdf created using jspdf?

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas

Hi I have converted my html page to canvas image and then turned that image to pdf using jspdf library. Now I want to call the ajax function `POST` or `$.post` function and send that pdf file link to backend and send it to email using our own email template. In that email template, I have using `<a>` which should contain the url of that pdf that was passed from front-end. Following is some line of code I have used in my function.

**Index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
html2canvas(document.querySelector(".certificate_holder")).then(canvas => {
    image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    pdf.addImage(image.src, 'PNG', 0, 0);
    sendEmail(image.src)

    function sendEmail(pdflink){
            $.post("/pdfController/sendEmail",{link:pdflink}, function(data){
                console.log(data);
            })
        }    
</script>
```

In the above code, I am getting the image link using `toDataUrl` which is in Basecode(which is very long), instead I want actual link that I can use in `<a href="pdflink">`. Is there any way where I can generate or get a pdf-link using jspdf library?. Another alternative is getting a short actual link from Basecode URL that I have in above code which is `image.src`. Help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand fully what are you doing. Are you saving your PDF? Send the saved link to the backend.

Comment: @yomisimie I tried saving pdf like this: 
`pdf.save("certificate.pdf");`. Now as you mentioned sending the saved link to back-end, it would be great if you can tell me how can I send the saved link to backend ?

Comment: You have to manually create the link then, your home URL + folder in which you save the file + file name. That should get you the final url so you can access the file.

Comment: Got you. Will try that. Thankyou. I appreciate

Comment: I tried downloading file to my project folder. But it's not even downloading now. Instead showing an error "Invalid Regular Expressions Flags". So I tried to research on it and found that it is not possible to download a file at specific folder and it will save the file to default 'Download' folder. So are there any other options ?

Comment: Did you save the file on the server?

Comment: What do you mean by server ?

Comment: Well, if you want to send an URL to someone in the mail, the file has to be on a server. Are you running a local project?

Comment: Yes I am running it on local.

Comment: I would suggest using a server-side solution - something like PrinceXML or PhantomJS or even something sophisticated like https://github.com/alvarcarto/url-to-pdf-api

Comment: @IVOGELOV Thanks for your output, but my problem is to get the pdf url and send it to backend. I don't have any problem in generating PDF.

Comment: Actually your problem is sending/uploading the PDF to the backend and getting back the resulting URL into the frontend - the opposite of what you are stating. Are you asking how to upload a data URI (saved from a Canvas) with AJAX ? Simply do `canvas.toBlob(myCallback,"image/jpeg",0.8)` and in the callback create a FormData object and add the blob data (1st arg of the callback) to the FormData. Browser will add the proper headers in the XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Can you show me example or if you can provide a link from where I can learn. Thanks

Comment: You may take a look at this CodePen https://codepen.io/TMCDOS/pen/LrwJLx